# Sympy not isolating unknown variable from equation

Tags: python, sympy

I have a system of two equations with two unknown variables. I am trying to use Sympy to extract the value of one of the unknown variables as a function of only known variables. However, when I use the `solve()` function, the output is a function of both known and unknown variables.

I wrote this script for isolating the variable in question, however it returns a function which includes both X_ai and Y_ao. How can I make sure the function for calculating the value of `X_ai` is only a function of the known values?

```
from sympy import symbols, solve

# Known values
X_0 = symbols('X_0', positive=True)
Y_0 = symbols('Y_0', positive=True)

X_vi = symbols('X_vi', positive=True)
Y_vo = symbols('Y_vo', positive=True)

# Unknown values
X_ai = symbols('X_ai', positive=True)
Y_ao = symbols('Y_ao', positive=True)

eq_Y_ao = Y_0 - ((Y_vo * (((X_0 + X_ai) * 1000) + (X_vi * 997))) / (X_vi * 997))
eq_X_ai = 1 + ((X_0 * Y_ao * 1000) / ((Y_0 - Y_ao) * 997)) - X_ai

eq_X_ai.subs(Y_ao, eq_Y_ao)

# At this point, the equation eq_X_ai contains only a single unknown value (X_ai), which I would like to isolate

print(solve([eq_X_ai], [X_ai]))

# Now the equation contains Y_ao, which is unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy expressions are immutable so subs returns a new expression rather than changing the original expression:

```
In [8]: eq_X_ai
Out[8]: 
  1000⋅X₀⋅Yₐₒ             
──────────────── - Xₐᵢ + 1
997⋅Y₀ - 997⋅Yₐₒ          

In [9]: eq_X_ai.subs(Y_ao, eq_Y_ao)
Out[9]: 
            ⎛     Yᵥₒ⋅(1000⋅X₀ + 1000⋅Xₐᵢ + 997⋅Xᵥᵢ)⎞          
1000⋅X₀⋅Xᵥᵢ⋅⎜Y₀ - ──────────────────────────────────⎟          
            ⎝                  997⋅Xᵥᵢ              ⎠          
───────────────────────────────────────────────────── - Xₐᵢ + 1
         Yᵥₒ⋅(1000⋅X₀ + 1000⋅Xₐᵢ + 997⋅Xᵥᵢ)                    

In [10]: eq_X_ai
Out[10]: 
  1000⋅X₀⋅Yₐₒ             
──────────────── - Xₐᵢ + 1
997⋅Y₀ - 997⋅Yₐₒ          

In [11]: eq = eq_X_ai.subs(Y_ao, eq_Y_ao) # assign to eq

In [12]: eq
Out[12]: 
            ⎛     Yᵥₒ⋅(1000⋅X₀ + 1000⋅Xₐᵢ + 997⋅Xᵥᵢ)⎞          
1000⋅X₀⋅Xᵥᵢ⋅⎜Y₀ - ──────────────────────────────────⎟          
            ⎝                  997⋅Xᵥᵢ              ⎠          
───────────────────────────────────────────────────── - Xₐᵢ + 1
         Yᵥₒ⋅(1000⋅X₀ + 1000⋅Xₐᵢ + 997⋅Xᵥᵢ)                    

In [13]: print(solve([eq], [X_ai]))
[((sqrt(Y_vo)*(-1997000*X_0 - 994009*X_vi + 997000) - sqrt(9000000*X_0**2*Y_vo + 3976036000000*X_0*X_vi*Y_0 - 5964054000*X_0*X_vi*Y_vo - 5982000000*X_0*Y_vo + 988053892081*X_vi**2*Y_vo + 1982053946000*X_vi*Y_vo + 994009000000*Y_vo))/(1994000*sqrt(Y_vo)),), ((sqrt(Y_vo)*(-1997000*X_0 - 994009*X_vi + 997000) + sqrt(9000000*X_0**2*Y_vo + 3976036000000*X_0*X_vi*Y_0 - 5964054000*X_0*X_vi*Y_vo - 5982000000*X_0*Y_vo + 988053892081*X_vi**2*Y_vo + 1982053946000*X_vi*Y_vo + 994009000000*Y_vo))/(1994000*sqrt(Y_vo)),)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sympy Expressions are immutable, `expr.subs` returns a new expression instead of modifying `expr`. See [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) for more examples.
I figured this out by pasting your script into the interactive interpreter and seeing that the `subs` line returned a value.

This means the statement

```py
eq_X_ai.subs(Y_ao, eq_Y_ao)
```

does not modify the object stored in the python variable `eq_X_ai`, and you should use

```
eq_X_ai = eq_X_ai.subs(Y_ao, eq_Y_ao)
```

instead.